# How to categorize packets according to different TCP connections

Tags: session, networking, hadoop, tcp, pcap

I have captured packets in a pcap file.
I have to **identify all packets of particular TCP connection in a session**. And want to generate **same unique key for set of all packets of a session** (i.e. it is different for same connection's different different sessions).

Here one session means (for example: if there is connection established between s1 and s2 then session1 starts, if this connection closes and again same connection established between s1 and s2 then new session will start eg: session2)

Please tell me the approach for:
 
**1. Identify the packets with same session.

2. Assign some unique key for packets of that session by using it's attribute.**

**Note:** Packets may be in nonconsecutive order.

I want to use these key for mapping packets in Hadoop.

Comment: The approach is to make yourself familiar with parsing pcap and with the properties of the TCP/IP protocol and then come back if you have specific questions. This question here is way too broad.